# Format MultiLine Text File

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk

As a result of a `**grep -e "Full Name" -e "Address" -e "Celphone"|awk '{$1=$1;print}'**` (in a bash file), i have the following:

```
Full Name: Person A<p>
Address: Address A<p>
Celphone: Celphone A<p>
Full Name: Person B<p>
Address: Address B<p>
Full Name: Person C<p>
Address: Address C<p>
Full Name: Person D<p>
Address: Address D<p>
Celphone: Celphone D<p>
```

However, i want to have as a final output something like below:

```
Full Name: Person A , Address: Address A, Celphone: Celphone A<p>
Full Name: Person B , Address: Address B<p>
Full Name: Person C , Address: Address C<p>
Full Name: Person D , Address: Address D, Celphone: Celphone D<p>
```

My challenge is that the line **Celphone** is not always present in the file and i don't know how to have this "conditional concatenation".

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the initial file content

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `awk` command.

```
awk -F':' '{if(NR==1){printf("%s",$0)}else if($1~"Full Name"){printf("\n%s",$0)} else{printf(",%s",$0)}}' file
```

It will return:

```
Full Name: Person A<p>,Address: Address A<p>,Celphone: Celphone A<p>
Full Name: Person B<p>,Address: Address B<p>
Full Name: Person C<p>,Address: Address C<p>
Full Name: Person D<p>,Address: Address D<p>,Celphone: Celphone D<p>
```

But I noticed in your output There is no `<p>` in between the line. If you really want like that then you can try below command:

```
awk -F':' '{if(NR==1){printf("%s",$0)}else if($1~"Full Name"){printf("\n%s",$0)} else{printf(" , %s",$0)}}' test.txt | sed 's/<p> ,/ ,/g'
```

It will return:

```
Full Name: Person A , Address: Address A , Celphone: Celphone A<p>
Full Name: Person B , Address: Address B<p>
Full Name: Person C , Address: Address C<p>
Full Name: Person D , Address: Address D , Celphone: Celphone D<p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed  ':a;N;/\nFull Name:/!s/<p>\n/, /;ta;P;D' file
```

Gather up the lines for a complete record, replacing the `<p>` and the following newline by `,`. Then print the new record and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^Full/{x;s/\n/, /g;1!p;d;};H;${g;s/\n/, /g;p;}' filename
```